# Draw a circle smaller than 0.1 using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a bullet point (filled circle) with Tikz. With the following code, I can draw the circle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [draw, shape = circle, fill = black, minimum size = 0.1cm] (){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to draw a smaller point, but decreasing the `minimum size = 0.1 cm` to, say, `0.0001 cm` does not make a difference. I am wondering what the cause of this behaviour is, and how to fix it?

Comment: I suspect that it is allowing some space for the text of your `\node` -- why don't you just use `\fill (0,0) circle [radius=0.01mm];` ?  Section 2 of the manual explains the basic path operations.

Comment: @Thruston Sounds like a potential answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I currently use it in this format: `\node(legend) at (1.7,-6.85) {Test: }; 
    \node [right=0.2cm of legend, draw, shape = circle, fill = black, minimum size = 0.1cm, inner sep = 1.5pt] (status1){};` But cannot seem to get you answer to work.

Comment: TikZ nodes are intended to contain text.  Even an empty text field will require 2 inner sep worth of space (about 0.666em).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add in node options the following

```
\node [draw, shape = circle, fill = black, minimum size = 0.1cm, inner sep=0pt] (){};
```